# Crash while unwrapping an Optional Value

Tags: swift

I am getting an error. It is returning nil on a DispatchQueue call.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.headerImageView.image = image // <- CRASH
}
```

Turns out that this is where I am getting a crash.

`headerImageView` is just a variable which is not connected to the storyboard via `IBOutlet`. Here is the entire code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

let offset_HeaderStop:CGFloat = 40.0
let offset_B_LabelHeader:CGFloat = 95.0
let distance_W_LabelHeader:CGFloat = 35.0

class MovieDetailsViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var movie: Movie?
    var urlBuilder = MovieUrlBuilder()
    var config = TMDBConfiguration()

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var headerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var genreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var releaseLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var trailerContainerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var trailerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var videoContainer: WKWebView!

    var headerImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        headerImageView = UIImageView(frame: headerView.bounds)
        headerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Poster")
        headerImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        headerView.insertSubview(headerImageView, belowSubview: headerLabel)
        headerView.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        fetchPopularMovies()
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        var headerTransform = CATransform3DIdentity

        if offset < 0 {
            let headerScaleFactor: CGFloat = -(offset) / headerView.bounds.height
            let headerSizeVariation = ((headerView.bounds.height * (1.0 + headerScaleFactor)) - headerView.bounds.height)/2.0
            headerTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(headerTransform, 0, headerSizeVariation, 0)
            headerTransform = CATransform3DScale(headerTransform, 1.0 + headerScaleFactor, 1.0 + headerScaleFactor, 0)

            headerView.layer.transform = headerTransform
        } else { 
            headerTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(headerTransform, 0, max(-offset_HeaderStop, -offset), 0)
            let labelTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, max(-distance_W_LabelHeader, offset_B_LabelHeader - offset), 0)
            headerLabel.layer.transform = labelTransform
        }

        headerView.layer.transform = headerTransform
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
        return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    }

    private func fetchPopularMovies() {
        if let poster = movie?.backdropPath {
            let baseURL = URL(string: config.baseImageURL)!
            let url = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("w500").appendingPathComponent(poster)
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)

            let task = urlBuilder.session.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
                do {
                    if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.headerImageView.image = image // <- CRASH
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing the image view in `viewDidAppear` which will be called **after** `viewWillAppear` where the image view is populated. Despite the asynchronous task it's not guaranteed that the view is initialized before being populated.

I recommend to initialize the image view lazily, the benefit is that the property is non-optional and it's initialized once when it's accessed the first time.

```
 lazy var headerImageView: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView(frame: self.headerView.bounds)
    view.image = UIImage(named: "Poster")
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    self.headerView.insertSubview(view, belowSubview: self.headerLabel)
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    return view
 }()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your async call is located in `fetchPopularMovies`, which is called at `viewWillAppear`. You initialise your image view in `viewDidAppear`, which is called *after* `viewWillAppear`.

Basically, `headerImageView` is nil.

"But I put the call in an `async` block! So `viewDidAppear` should have been called already when I set the image view's image, right?" you said.

Well, relying on `async` to say "I want this thing to run after a certain method returns" is not a good idea. It is not always guaranteed to do that.

To fix this, you need to initialise header image view *before* `fetchPopularMovies` is called. You can put it in `viewDidLoad` for example.